# Duvida quanto ao uso de json_encode e json_decode

Tags: php, json

Quando e como devemos usar `json_encode` e `json_decode`? Para que servem?

Answer (score 8):

Sempre que precisares de enviar dados entre o servidor e cliente, ou uma API, ou gravar dados num formato estruturado podes usar o formato JSON.

JSON é uma string, e para trabalhar esses dados em PHP precisas de os interpretar, para isso usas o `json_decode`.

Sempre que precisares de transformar dados numa string de texto JSON para enviar ou guardar podes usar o `json_encode`.

**Para converter de string JSON:**

```
$string_json = '["item1","item2"]';
$array = json_decode($string_json);
var_dump($array); // dá uma array:

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "item1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "item2"
}
```

**Para converter para string JSON:**

```
$array = array('item1', 'item2');
$string_json = json_encode($array);
echo $string_json; // dá uma string: '["item1","item2"]'
```

Comment: Agradeço muito!! estou fazendo um curso, e chegamos nesta parte mais não ficou muito claro pra mim. !! Obrigado pela instrução!!!

Comment: você inverteu os códigos.

Comment: @HENRIQUELOBO haha :) obrigado. Editei e corrigi.

Answer (score 2):

O JSON é apenas um formato estruturado de escrita de arquivos, ou seja, é uma alternativa equivalente a **xml** ou **csv**.

Geralmente, o formato JSON é utilizado para o trafego de informações entre [API's restful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), banco de dados não relacionais, e até mesmo utilizada dentro da programação em javascript.

Exemplificando melhor os usos do json, é possivel que eu escreva as mesmas informações de varias maneiras, exemplos:

***Formato JSON***

```
{
    [
        "nome": "João",
        "idade": 22
    ],
    [
        "nome": "José",
        "idade": 25
    ],
}
```

***Formato CSV***

```
Nome;Idade;
"João", 22
"José", 25
```

***Formato XML***

```
<pessoa>
    <nome>"João"</nome>
    <idade>22</idade>
</pessoa>
<pessoa>
    <nome>"José"</nome>
    <idade>25</idade>
</pessoa>
```

Percebeu que apesar do formato todos eles conseguem portar o mesmo conteudo? A única coisa que define que tipo usar é a necessidade de aplicação, e os `decodes` citados são apenas para coletar essas informações e traduzi-las para o PHP.